# django NodeNotFoundError Migration employee.0001_initial dependencies on ('auth', '0013_auto_20191031_1253')

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i am getting error while migrating in deployment like 
`django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration employee.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0013_auto_20191031_1253')`

but my migration file working fine in local pc with mysql db 
like

```
Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_auto_20190907_1107... OK
  Applying auth.0013_auto_20191031_1253... OK
  Applying employee.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying authtoken.0001_initial... OK
  Applying authtoken.0002_auto_20160226_1747... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

but in linux server i am getting error

and i am using custom User model from AbstractUser called User in the same models.py file and give to one to one link employee model like

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and this is migration file

```
import datetime
from django.conf import settings
import django.contrib.auth.models
import django.contrib.auth.validators
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0013_auto_20191031_1253'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
```

what i tried is i removed my migration files
then i migrated basic stuff and `showmigrations` is (worked fine)

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [X] 0012_auto_20190816_1629
 [X] 0013_auto_20190912_1616
authtoken
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20160226_1747
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

then i recreated the my migration file  like `employee.0001_initial` then again i did `python manage.py migrate` but same `node error`

Comment: issue solved. i was using different virtual packages in local and server